# Server: Using Active Directory Groups For Sudo Fails Unless Name of File in /etc/sudoers Matches The Name Of The AD Group

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, sssd

I work for an organization with many linux servers that we'd like to start authenticating with Active Directory. I have a proof-of-concept server set up on which I use SSSD and Kerberos to authenticate with Active Directory. Currently, I have it set up so that only users from a certain group (we'll call it group-A) can log into the server, and this is working properly. Next, I set about making it so that users from another group (group-B) automatically have sudo permissions. Here's the structure of the organizational units in our Active Directory:

**group-A**

[image: Group-A structure]

**group-B**

[image: Group-B Structure]

I can successfully log in as an active directory user, and I have included my sssd.conf below:

```
[sssd]
services = nss, pam
config_file_version = 2
domains = <organization>.LOCAL

[domain/<organization>.LOCAL]
id_provider = ad
access_provider = ad

# Use this if users are being logged in at /.
# This example specifies /home/DOMAIN-FQDN/user as /root.  Use with pam_mkhomedir.so
override_homedir = /home/%d/%u

# makes all users use bash as the default shell
override_shell = /bin/bash

# only allows users from the following groups to log in
ad_access_filter = (|(memberOf=cn=group-A,ou=Groups,ou=department,dc=organization,dc=local))
```

In order to allow all members of group-B sudo rights, I created a file named group-B-admin-group in `/etc/sudoers.d` that has the following content:

```
%group-B    ALL=(ALL)   ALL
```

at this point, I could not use sudo even with users who were in group-B. Executing `sudo su` would immediately require the password, and then report that the user was not in the sudoers file. Executing `sudo touch this`, `sudo cat`, `sudo vim`, and other such commands would require me to wait ~60s before asking me for my password. Upon entering my password, sudo reported that I was not in the sudoers file. At this point, I renamed the file `/etc/sudoers.d/group-B-admin-group` to `/etc/sudoers.d/group-B` and suddenly everything works fine. Users in group-B are immediately presented with a prompt for their password and then run the program with elevated privelages.

**My question is this:** I thought that the name of the file was moot (you can put permissions for multiple users/groups in one file, anyways.) Is part of my configuration requiring the name of the group and file to be the same? I just want to understand why this is behaving the way it does